# Are there any ways to tell from geolocation data whether we're near an international border, which other countries are near the current location?

Tags: geolocation, internationalization, countries

For a travel-related app idea I have it would be great to not only determine the user's location, but also if any other countries are near that location.

Are there any options that make something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these open-sourced Geo JSON libraries on GitHub.

https://github.com/topojson/world-atlas

https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json

https://github.com/topojson/us-atlas